# Arithmatic Operations On Columns Using Same Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, arithmetic-expressions

I have a column and I want to perform some arithmetic operation on the same column using the same column

```
Price
---------
10
11
12
12
14
14
14
14
```

If I want to know rows with Price=14 then I can write a simple select query with where clause

```
select * from table_name where Price = 14;
```

But the value of Price column keeps changing and if I want something like this

```
Latest value of Price is 10
select * from table_name where Price = Price + 4;
```

This should return all rows with value 14. How do we achieve this?

Comment: How do you know what the "latest" value of `Price` is in your table?

Answer (score 0):

use  subquery

```
 select * from table_name where Price = (select min(Price) + 4 from table_name)
```

Comment: The next value of Price can be 13 then the query would return incorrect value

Comment: @user3198755 what is the logic to get the latest value from your data it seems min so i used that

Comment: The only logic that I know is that we are going to add 4 to whatever the latest price is

Comment: @user3198755 if you dont know the logic of latest then you could not solve it here main focus is to know about latest based what